# node.js/ read 100 first bytes of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read a file in parts: the first 100 bytes and then on..
I'm trying to read the first 100 bytes of the `/npm` file:

```
app.post('/random', function(req, res) {
    var start = req.body.start;
    var fileName = './npm';
    var contentLength = req.body.contentlength;
    var file = randomAccessFile(fileName + 'read');
    console.log("Start is: " + start);
    console.log("ContentLength is: " + contentLength);
    fs.open(fileName, 'r', function(status, fd) {
        if (status) {
            console.log(status.message);
            return;
        }
        var buffer = new Buffer(contentLength);
        fs.read(fd, buffer, start, contentLength, 0, function(err, num) {
            console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8', 0, num));
        });
    });
```

the output is:

```
Start is: 0
ContentLength is: 100
```

and the next error:

```
fs.js:457
  binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, wrapper);
          ^
Error: Length extends beyond buffer
    at Object.fs.read (fs.js:457:11)
    at C:\NodeInst\node\FileSys.js:132:12
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're confusing the offset and position argument. From [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback):

> `offset` is the offset in the buffer to start writing at.
>
> `position` is an integer specifying where to begin reading from in the file. If position is null, data will be read from the current file position.

You should change your code to this:

```
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, contentLength, start, function(err, num) {
        console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8', 0, num));
    });
```

Basically the `offset` is will be index that fs.read will write to the buffer. Let's say you have a buffer with length of 10 like this: `<Buffer 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a>` and you will read from `/dev/zero` which is basically only zeros, and set the offset to 3 and set the length to 4 then you will get this: `<Buffer 01 02 03 00 00 00 00 08 09 0a>`.

```
fs.open('/dev/zero', 'r', function(status, fd) {
    if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
    }
    var buffer = new Buffer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 3, 4, 0, function(err, num) {
        console.log(buffer);
    });
});
```

Also to make things you might wanna try using [`fs.createStream`](https://iojs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options):

```
app.post('/random', function(req, res) {
    var start = req.body.start;
    var fileName = './npm';
    var contentLength = req.body.contentlength;
    fs.createReadStream(fileName, { start : start, end: contentLength - 1 })
        .pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the file descriptor: `fs.close(fd);`

Answer (score 5):

Since node 10 there is the experimental `Readable[Symbol.asyncIterator]` (that is no more experimental in node v12).

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

async function run() {
  const file = 'hello.csv';
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { encoding: 'utf8', start: 0, end: 100 });
  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    console.log(`${file} >>> ${chunk}`);
  }

  // or if you don't want the for-await-loop
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { encoding: 'utf8', start: 0, end: 100 });
  const firstByte = await stream[Symbol.asyncIterator]().next();
  console.log(`${file} >>> ${firstByte.value}`);
}

run();
```

Will print out the first bites